# shell script to query arp table and send it via restful API?

Tags: linux, shell, networking

I want to create a shell script which can query the arp table and then call a restful api to send it.

The purpose is that I want to get the MAC address of all connected devices from the arp table and use the restful API to send it to server for further handling e.g. ip-mac translation.

Is there any example for doing this?

Comment: you can get the arp cache by `arp` command, but can you describe more detail what you wan't to achieve by writing some example codes?

Comment: I don't have any code here as i have no idea yet how to do it.But what i want to achieve is that i want to get the arp table and send it to the server via restful api. So the server can make a translation of ip address to MAC.

Comment: then can you elaborate what `query the arp table` and `call a restful api` means? maybe your question is so vague.

Comment: I want to get the MAC address of all connected devices from the arp table and use the restful API to send it to server for further handling e.g. ip-mac translation.

Comment: maybe you are looking for a command like `arp | grep -v 'incomplete' | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $3}' | while read line; do wget http://restful_url/$line; done`, but i'm not sure

Comment: @ymonad, yes, this is quite close to what i need. I need to resend the arp table when it changes. How to detect it or do i just need to send it periodically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59974/discussion-between-mullex-and-ymonad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [arp](http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/man/arp.8.html) command is deprecated in favor of iproute2's [`ip neighbour`](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-neighbor.html) command. However the question is if you dont want to use something like `arpwatch` (and [arpwatch NG](http://freequaos.host.sk/arpwatch/)) it will track and alert by itself. This is better, as it does not rely on the subset of cached arp entries, but on all announcements sniffed on the wire.